# Function name must be a string (symfony/flex) afer composer require but not update

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony4

Installing some bundles in symfony 4 when I execute the command I get the same error over and over:

> Command:

```
composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet secit-pl/imap-bundle tbbc/money-bundle
```

> Erro with stack trace

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in /var/www/skeleton/vendor/symfony/flex/src/ParallelDownloader.php:246
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/skeleton/vendor/symfony/flex/src/ParallelDownloader.php(84): Symfony\Flex\ParallelDownloader->getNext()
#1 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php(195) : eval()'d code(452): Symfony\Flex\ParallelDownloader->download(Array, Object(Closure))
#2 [internal function]: Symfony\Flex\Flex_composer_tmp1->populateProvidersCacheDir(Object(Composer\Installer\InstallerEvent))
#3 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(176): call_user_func(Array, Object(Composer\Installer\InstallerEvent))
#4 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(135): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(Object(Composer\Installer\InstallerEvent))
#5 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php(471): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher- in /var/www/skeleton/vendor/symfony/flex/src/ParallelDownloader.php on line 246

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in /var/www/skeleton/vendor/symfony/flex/src/ParallelDownloader.php:246
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/skeleton/vendor/symfony/flex/src/ParallelDownloader.php(84): Symfony\Flex\ParallelDownloader->getNext()
#1 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php(195) : eval()'d code(452): Symfony\Flex\ParallelDownloader->download(Array, Object(Closure))
#2 [internal function]: Symfony\Flex\Flex_composer_tmp1->populateProvidersCacheDir(Object(Composer\Installer\InstallerEvent))
#3 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(176): call_user_func(Array, Object(Composer\Installer\InstallerEvent))
#4 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(135): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(Object(Composer\Installer\InstallerEvent))
#5 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php(471): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher- in /var/www/skeleton/vendor/symfony/flex/src/ParallelDownloader.php on line 246
```

> Environment

1. OS: Ubuntu 16.04
2. PHP: 7.2.5

That only happens when I use composer require I just did an update and updated some packages included the ones which flex didn't install but didn't throw any error

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a recent bug raised in Flex `1.0.81`, upgrade to `1.0.82` (which is the same as `1.0.80`) as a hotfix.

Ref: https://github.com/symfony/flex/issues/381

Comment: I already saw that post but it didn't solve my issue. I have updated today, that  issue was solved yesterday. when I run composer update the output is "nothing to update or install". When I run composer show symfony/flex the version is dev-master. Is up to date

Comment: @JuanI.MoralesPestana the dev-master version has the same issue than `1.0.81`, use tag `1.0.82`.

Comment: Thanks, already noticed. I just target the v 1.0.82 and all works fine.